# Why I am not able to add in-app or subscription to my Google Play Console?

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am a bit puzzled about what to do for adding subscriptions and in-app to the Android version (flutter).

The console says: "Your app gets no app for the moment" and "in order to as in-app, you must include BILLING permission in your APK"

[image]

But in the app bundle I just added inAndroidManifest.xml and uploaded to the google play console (though not deployed yet):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
</manifest>
```

Not sure this is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution.

By 2023, `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/> </manifest>`is handled by the 'BILLING' module, so you don't need to ad it in the manifest by yourself.

Instead, in `android/app/build.gradle`, add the following line in the `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies {
   // blah blah

    def billing_version = "5.1.0" // for today, it's the latest
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
}
```

Crete the app bundle by doing:

```
flutter build app bundle
```

Then, you need to create a closed test (I really don't know why an internal test does not make it through) and deploy your bundle.

Once you did, you get the UI in the Google play console where you can actually create in-apps or subscriptions.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution! Thank you for sharing it.